# How to install/use a local version of package using Stack?

Tags: haskell, package, cabal, haskell-stack

The situation is, I am trying to install Netwire using Stack. However, there is a problem in the latest netwire 5.0.1, as reported by dhobbs: http://hub.darcs.net/ertes/netwire/issue/13

Since I don't know when the problem will ever be fixed, I downloaded the repo and made the change myself. However, I don't understand how to install such a locally patched version. `stack install` does not install that into `~/.stack`. Does anyone have an idea?

**Update**

Now I am developing some other libraries using Stack. How do I make another project use that libraries? Hard coding a relative path looks incredibly ugly.

Answer (score 27):

So you have a project where you want to use your locally patched Netwire version and in your project you have a `stack.yml`, as an example:

```yaml
flags: {}
packages:
- '.'
extra-deps: {}
resolver: lts-3.7
```

You also have an dependency on `netwire` declared in your cabal file.

To use you patched Netwire in this project of yours you simply put the patched Netwire package in a subdirectory of your project, perhaps called `netwire`, and update your `stack.yml` as such:

```yaml
flags: {}
packages:
- '.'
- netwire
extra-deps: {}
resolver: lts-3.7
```

Now `stack build` will build your project with the patched Netwire version.

You can also put the modified source online (if the license permits) and refer to the *source* using either a tarball URL

```
- https://example.com/netwire.tar.gz
```

or a git repository and commit reference:

```
- location:
    git: git@example.com/netwire
    commit: 6a86ee32e5b869a877151f74064572225e1a0398
```

(Check out the documentation for more info: https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/yaml_configuration/#packages-and-extra-deps)

Comment: I know this method. However, I would like to put the netwire library at a more convenient place, isolated from the source. Doing what you said makes me feel like compiling a bunch of softwares under /usr and keep the sources right there.

Comment: Or say, I'd like it if I use `stack ghci` anywhere, I can just import `Control.Wire`

Comment: I'm not 100% but I don't think that is a supported use case.

Comment: Does that mean I have to keep the source then? I think it is better to just take the libraries

Comment: You can specify a git location as a package. See the docs on stack.yaml. That way you don't need to put the source in your project's directory. Sorry for no links, I'm on my phone.

Comment: AFAIK stack is a tool for building collections of packages from _source_, with the ability to cache some of the build artifiacts (the ones that are part of the Stackage nightlies/lts-s). Since Netwire is not part of Stackage I don't think you have any hope of it ending up in the cache.

Comment: OK, I guess for now I will just find a nice place to put the sources.

Comment: You can get around needing to have netwire as a subdirectory with a symlink. Just put it wherever you want and drop a symlink to it into your package. It's kind of a hack, but it will get the job done.

Comment: "You can also put the modified source online (if the license permits) and refer to the source using either a tarball URL" It seems that "packages" does not support this syntax in "stack.yaml"? it prompt InvalidAbsDir.