# `stack install` for library targets

Tags: haskell-stack

I'd like to have similar functionality as `stack install` (e.g. the `--copy-bins` flag) does for executables, but for libraries.

Currently, I have to `stack build` and then manually find the `libHS*-<version>-<fingerprint>.a` files in `.stack-work`. That is problematic/uncomfy for two reason:

1. I have to rely on the internal folder structure of stack (reliable enough, though)
2. I have to manually get rid of the fingerprint and the version

Well, I could work around both, I guess, but I'd like to know if this might already be available/sensible to implement.

---

Some background, which may or may not be relevant to the question rather than to its motivation:

I am playing around with https://hackage.haskell.org/package/dynamic-loader-0.0/docs/System-Plugins-DynamicLoader.html and want to provide as realistic an example as I can, so I plan to compile a package's object code into a `*.a` (containing the compilation of multiple modules) which I want to link in at runtime.

What I want to do works already for trivial single module files, where I only need to use `loadModule`. Currently I'm tinkering around with `loadPackage`.

Comment: I imagine you want to refer to a development/patched version of a library from another project that you are working on. The following answer should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32849269/how-to-install-use-a-local-version-of-package-using-stack.

Comment: Uhmm no, I'm talking about binary artifacts here, for the sake of separate compilation. Actually what I want with the produced static lib is to load it at runtime.

Comment: Rather than the `<lib>.a`, don't you want the `<lib>.so` (or what have you for your platform)?

Comment: That's a part I'm not sure about... I'm playing around with https://hackage.haskell.org/package/dynamic-loader-0.0/docs/System-Plugins-DynamicLoader.html . The API suggests to use object files, but there is also a function for DLLs. Regardless, it amounts to the same: I think there should be a way to 'deploy' both library types to a specified directory in their non-fingerprinted version.

Comment: I understand. It's probably worth mentioning in your question though.