# Haskell : Gloss error when trying to render a text

Tags: haskell, cabal, gloss

I am trying to run this example: 
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/elisehuard/game-in-haskell/master/src/Shapes.hs

But I get the error "freeglut  ERROR:  Function  called without first calling 'glutInit'."

I managed to isolate the problem to line 39 :  "Color (bright magenta) $ translate 0 (-100) $ scale 0.2 0.2 $ text "Boo!""

when I change it to : "Color (bright magenta) $ translate 0 (-100) $ scale 0.2 0.2 $ blank

It's working fine.

I am working on linux mint 19; Gloss version 1.13.0.1; gloss-rendering 1.13.0.2.

---

After Cloning gloss, building, and adding the new cloned lib to my stack

```html
malki@Hood:~/Projects/TstP$ stack build
TstP-0.1.0.0: build (lib + exe)
gloss-1.13.0.1: build (lib)
Completed 2 action(s).
Log files have been written to: /home/malki/Projects/TstP/.stack-work/logs/

--  While building package TstP-0.1.0.0 using:
      /home/malki/.stack/setup-exe-cache/x86_64-linux/Cabal-simple_mPHDZzAJ_2.2.0.1_ghc-8.4.4 --builddir=.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-2.2.0.1 build lib:TstP exe:TstP-exe --ghc-options " -ddump-hi -ddump-to-file"
    Process exited with code: ExitFailure 1
    Logs have been written to: /home/malki/Projects/TstP/.stack-work/logs/TstP-0.1.0.0.log

    Preprocessing library for TstP-0.1.0.0..
    Building library for TstP-0.1.0.0..
    Preprocessing executable 'TstP-exe' for TstP-0.1.0.0..
    Building executable 'TstP-exe' for TstP-0.1.0.0..
    [1 of 2] Compiling Main             ( app/Main.hs, .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-2.2.0.1/build/TstP-exe/TstP-exe-tmp/Main.o )
    
    /home/malki/Projects/TstP/app/Main.hs:5:1: error:
        Could not find module ‘Graphics.UI.GLFW’
        It is not a module in the current program, or in any known package.
      |
    5 | import "GLFW-b" Graphics.UI.GLFW as GLFW
      | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    
    /home/malki/Projects/TstP/app/Main.hs:6:1: error:
        Could not find module ‘Graphics.Gloss’
        Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
      |
    6 | import Graphics.Gloss
      | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    
    /home/malki/Projects/TstP/app/Main.hs:7:1: error:
        Could not find module ‘Graphics.Gloss.Rendering’
        Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
      |
    7 | import Graphics.Gloss.Rendering
      | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    
    /home/malki/Projects/TstP/app/Main.hs:8:1: error:
        Could not find module ‘Graphics.Gloss.Data.Color’
        Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
      |
    8 | import Graphics.Gloss.Data.Color
      | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    
    /home/malki/Projects/TstP/app/Main.hs:9:1: error:
        Could not find module ‘Graphics.Gloss.Data.Picture’
        Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
      |
    9 | import Graphics.Gloss.Data.Picture
      | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^


--  While building package gloss-1.13.0.1 using:
      /home/malki/.stack/setup-exe-cache/x86_64-linux/Cabal-simple_mPHDZzAJ_2.2.0.1_ghc-8.4.4 --builddir=.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-2.2.0.1 build lib:gloss --ghc-options " -ddump-hi -ddump-to-file"
    Process exited with code: ExitFailure 1
    Logs have been written to: /home/malki/Projects/TstP/.stack-work/logs/gloss-1.13.0.1.log

    Preprocessing library for gloss-1.13.0.1..
    Building library for gloss-1.13.0.1..
    [ 1 of 44] Compiling Graphics.Gloss.Data.Bitmap ( Graphics/Gloss/Data/Bitmap.hs, .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-2.2.0.1/build/Graphics/Gloss/Data/Bitmap.o ) [Graphics.Gloss.Rendering changed]
    
    /home/malki/Projects/TstP/gloss/gloss/Graphics/Gloss/Data/Bitmap.hs:15:1: error:
        Could not find module ‘Graphics.Gloss.Rendering’
        There are files missing in the ‘gloss-rendering-1.13.0.2’ package,
        try running 'ghc-pkg check'.
        Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
       |
    15 | import Graphics.Gloss.Rendering
       | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
malki@Hood:~/Projects/TstP$
```

These modules exists as global modules (things compile outside this stack dir). They are not present in the gloss-clone though.

```html
malki@Hood:~/Projects/TstP/gloss/gloss$ find ./Graphics
./Graphics
./Graphics/Gloss
./Graphics/Gloss/Geometry
./Graphics/Gloss/Geometry/Angle.hs
./Graphics/Gloss/Geometry/Line.hs
./Graphics/Gloss/Geometry.hs
./Graphics/Gloss/Interface
./Graphics/Gloss/Interface/Pure
./Graphics/Gloss/Interface/Pure/Simulate.hs
./Graphics/Gloss/Interface/Pure/Animate.hs
./Graphics/Gloss/Interface/Pure/Game.hs
./Graphics/Gloss/Interface/Pure/Display.hs
./Graphics/Gloss/Interface/IO
./Graphics/Gloss/Interface/IO/Simulate.hs
./Graphics/Gloss/Interface/IO/Animate.hs
./Graphics/Gloss/Interface/IO/Interact.hs
./Graphics/Gloss/Interface/IO/Game.hs
./Graphics/Gloss/Interface/IO/Display.hs
./Graphics/Gloss/Interface/Environment.hs
./Graphics/Gloss/Data
./Graphics/Gloss/Data/Vector.hs
./Graphics/Gloss/Data/Point.hs
./Graphics/Gloss/Data/ViewState.hs
./Graphics/Gloss/Data/ViewPort.hs
./Graphics/Gloss/Data/Color.hs
./Graphics/Gloss/Data/Point
./Graphics/Gloss/Data/Point/Arithmetic.hs
./Graphics/Gloss/Data/Bitmap.hs
./Graphics/Gloss/Data/Controller.hs
./Graphics/Gloss/Data/Picture.hs
./Graphics/Gloss/Data/Display.hs
./Graphics/Gloss/Internals
./Graphics/Gloss/Internals/Color.hs
./Graphics/Gloss/Internals/Interface
./Graphics/Gloss/Internals/Interface/Common
./Graphics/Gloss/Internals/Interface/Common/Exit.hs
./Graphics/Gloss/Internals/Interface/Event.hs
./Graphics/Gloss/Internals/Interface/ViewState
./Graphics/Gloss/Internals/Interface/ViewState/KeyMouse.hs
./Graphics/Gloss/Internals/Interface/ViewState/Motion.hs
./Graphics/Gloss/Internals/Interface/ViewState/Reshape.hs
./Graphics/Gloss/Internals/Interface/Simulate
./Graphics/Gloss/Internals/Interface/Simulate/Idle.hs
./Graphics/Gloss/Internals/Interface/Simulate/State.hs
./Graphics/Gloss/Internals/Interface/Simulate.hs
./Graphics/Gloss/Internals/Interface/Backend
./Graphics/Gloss/Internals/Interface/Backend/GLFW.hs
./Graphics/Gloss/Internals/Interface/Backend/GLUT.hs
./Graphics/Gloss/Internals/Interface/Backend/Types.hs
./Graphics/Gloss/Internals/Interface/Backend.hs
./Graphics/Gloss/Internals/Interface/Animate.hs
./Graphics/Gloss/Internals/Interface/Callback.hs
./Graphics/Gloss/Internals/Interface/Interact.hs
./Graphics/Gloss/Internals/Interface/Animate
./Graphics/Gloss/Internals/Interface/Animate/Timing.hs
./Graphics/Gloss/Internals/Interface/Animate/State.hs
./Graphics/Gloss/Internals/Interface/Debug.hs
./Graphics/Gloss/Internals/Interface/Game.hs
./Graphics/Gloss/Internals/Interface/Window.hs
./Graphics/Gloss/Internals/Interface/Display.hs
./Graphics/Gloss.hs
malki@Hood:~/Projects/TstP/gloss/gloss$
```

Isn't the local Graphic branch supposed to shadow the existing one? It seems that it tries to replace it in full.

---

Please advise!

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Gloss is compiled to run **either** with GLFW **or** GLUT - see [`Backend.hs`](https://github.com/benl23x5/gloss/blob/master/gloss/Graphics/Gloss/Internals/Interface/Backend.hs):

```
#ifdef WITHGLUT
defaultBackendState :: GLUTState
#elif  WITHGLFW
defaultBackendState :: GLFWState
#else
#error No default backend defined
#endif
```

`WITHGLUT` and `WITHGLFW` are compile-time flags specified when building the package. The code you're trying to run manually sets up a GLFW window, then uses gloss to render things: it looks like the gloss you're using is compiled to use GLUT instead of GLFW, so the setup that's been done manually isn't sufficient.

---

You'll need to recompile gloss to use GLFW instead:

```
git clone https://github.com/benl23x5/gloss
cd gloss
stack build --flag gloss:glfw --flag gloss:-glut
```

You may need to tweak the build files to fix errors during the build: stack's pretty good at explaining what you need to fix. I had to:

- Add `GLFW-b-1.4.8.4@sha256:2d10594c5cfa9d5178596eb6a18106a1318409e47a4108bfe91b89d80684638e` to the `extra-deps` of `stack.yaml`
- Add `Graphics.Gloss.Internals.Interface.Backend.GLUT` to `Other-modules` in `gloss.cabal`.

You can then modify the build files for the example you're trying to run to make `stack` use your local version of the package [as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32849269/how-to-install-use-a-local-version-of-package-using-stack).

Comment: After cloning gloss & building, I get a bunch of errors about missing modules:
Could not find module ‘Graphics.Gloss.Rendering’
I have gloss-rendering installed globally. I don't see it in the gloss clone though...

Comment: @finuux If it's not in the top directory of the cloned repo then it's a git issue - you should be running those commands from the same directory as the stack-x.y.yaml files. It would help if you edited your answer to quote the exact errors you get.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I am new to stack-overflow. I edited with errors...