# Using a package that's not on Hackage

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I am trying to use EuterpeaLite (https://github.com/Euterpea/EuterpeaLite), but it is not on Hackage.

I imported it like such `import EuterpeaLite as EL` and I added it to my cabal file like this:

```
build-depends:
base >=4.7 && <5
, postgresql-simple
, EuterpeaLite
```

But when I run `stack build` or `stack ghci`, I get this error:

```
Error: While constructing the build plan, the following exceptions were encountered:

In the dependencies for engine-0.1.0.0:

EuterpeaLite needed, but the stack configuration has no specified version (no package with that name found, perhaps there

is a typo in a package's build-depends or an omission from the stack.yaml packages list?)

needed since engine is a build target.

Some different approaches to resolving this:

Plan construction failed.
```

Is there a special process for non-Hackage packages?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install/use a local version of package using Stack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32849269/how-to-install-use-a-local-version-of-package-using-stack)

Comment: I tried this: `packages:
 - deepseq-1.4.4.0
 - Euterpea-2.0.7@sha256:81d583a47d483bf83ac07df7b764138f1aa52a56db4e7c7f685d070dbac4b388,2661
 - location: 
    git: https://github.com/Euterpea/EuterpeaLite.git
    commit: 5fe2d129bd3087dd78c0feaf4d35fc03ffd36215` and received the same error.

Comment: @LevelChart8 You need to put it in `extra-deps`, not `packages`. `packages` is used to list the packages in your Stack project; `extra-deps` is used to list any extra dependencies which aren’t in your Stack resolver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the following procedure.

1. Create a new stack project `stack new myproject --resolver=14.27`.  I needed to specify an older resolver, since EuterpeaLite wouldn't build with `lts-15.3`
2. In the `myproject` directory, add the following lines to `stack.yaml`:

   ```
   extra-deps:
   - git: https://github.com/Euterpea/EuterpeaLite.git
     commit: 5fe2d129bd3087dd78c0feaf4d35fc03ffd36215
   ```
3. Also in the `myproject` directory, I added the following dependency to `package.yaml`:

   ```
   dependencies:
   - base >= 4.7 && < 5
   - EuterpeaLite           # <- added this line
   ```
4. Ran `stack build` in the `myproject` directory.

As you noted, instead of using `package.yaml`, you could change your `.cabal` file.