# how to use a my own Haskell library in a stack project?

Tags: haskell, cabal, haskell-stack

I have a Haskell library I wrote that I compile with stack.
I now need to use it in another Haskell stack project.
In order to do that, I have added its current version to the `extra_deps` of my new project's `stack.yaml` and listed it among the `build_depends` of one its executables.
When I run `stack build`, however, it obviously tries to download the library from the internet. How do I specify that the library is local and where to find it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install/use a local version of package using Stack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32849269/how-to-install-use-a-local-version-of-package-using-stack)

Comment: @DDub, that answer is very old. With my version of Stack I'm getting an error: "Ignoring unrecognized field $.packages"

Comment: have you runned `stack install` or just `stack build`?. I think (not sure) that `stack install` command will add the compiled library to local dependencies. Once you've done that you can import from other package.

Comment: @DDub it's exactly the kind of answer I was looking for, but as michid says it no longer works.

Comment: @Ismor: I tried and it didn't work, I believe that's because stack only installs executables (and not libraries)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [github coordinates](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/pantry/#git-and-mercurial-repos) in the `extra-deps` section of your `stack.yaml`.

```
extra-deps:
- github: snoyberg/http-client
  commit: a5f4f30f01366738f913968163d856366d7e0342
```

Then add the dependency in your `package.yaml`:

```
dependencies:
- http-client >= 0.1.0.0
```

Comment: I was asking about how to use a _local_ library, but this with github did solve my problem. Thank you for your help!